# How much water does my square foot vegetable garden really need if I'm using drip irrigation?

Tags: vegetables, watering, drip-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much water should I give my veggies every day?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/how-much-water-should-i-give-my-veggies-every-day)

I recently installed a drip irrigation kit in my square foot garden with 1GPH heads aimed at the center of each square foot region.

The instructions say to run the system for 30-60 minutes every 1 to 4 days depending on temperature, which comes out to anywhere from 60 minutes per day to 30 minutes every 4 days. If my math is correct, that's anywhere from 1.4" to ***11"*** per week!

11" per week seems very excessive even in the heat of summer for where we are (Zone 10), yet 1.4" per week supplied via 30 minute waterings every 4 days seems like way too little in this heat.

I don't mind going through the cost/effort of adding extra lower/higher flow heads where appropriate, but I'd rather avoid ruining my crops due to experimenting with vague watering requirements from multiple sources.

Is there a good resource for watering requirements (volume and frequency) based on temperature for different types of vegetables that I could refer to in order to optimize my system?

In the mean time, what watering schedule could I use in general to keep my plants healthy?